# Is it possible to use Bitcoin Core Qt as interface for DIFFERENT full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

bitcoind is running on the background, local RPC server is running, all good. But is it now possible to have GUI? To say to bitcoin-qt that it should use RPC instead of going to disk files (which are locked by the other instance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no support for this. It is not an interface which uses the RPC interface, it has much deeper access within the wallet than RPC provides.